# Ideal hosting specs for Facebook apps

Tags: facebook, hosting

Apart from SSL, what features would one look for when searching for a host for Facebook apps?

In the context of small scale stuff - simple apps (PHP) and low usage volumes.

For example, would it be a good idea to find a host that is located near Facebook's own datacentre to help speed things up?

Answer (score 0):

A shared server will be enough if you have a few hundred users a day on the app. I have gone through all phases of user trends from only 10 page views a day to now everyday above 1 lakh page views a day.. For a simple app shared is ok.. if you doing heavy memory stuff than a vps will be enough.. if you have much more users than you expected than go for a dedicated. So start with a shared. I got one in the start from host gator and still works good for small apps.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, this is useful. Do you think it makes sense to host on a server that is geographically close to where Facebook is? I'm in Australia, and are worried that plugging into FB via the open graph may    lag a bit if my stuff is hosted locally.